# How to make cookieJar compatible so puppeteer can set them to browser correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, puppeteer

I extract some cookies via  a jar from a response (via  GET request) and was wondering whether I could convert them to JSON and use them in puppeteer to load a page with these cookies.

Tried:

Format of cookieJar:

```
jar: RequestJar {
    _jar: CookieJar {
      enableLooseMode: true,
      store: { idx: {
        'example.com': {
          '/': {
            frontend: Cookie="frontend=n7hnfv8971ai4lkcgvqs1m500s; Expires=Sun, 30 Jun 2019 11:51:59 GMT; Max-Age=86400; Domain=wellgosh.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; hostOnly=false; aAge=18ms; cAge=16864ms",
            frontend_cid: Cookie="frontend_cid=fGjhTirhLEc2XovB; Expires=Sun, 30 Jun 2019 11:51:59 GMT; Max-Age=86400; Domain=wellgosh.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; hostOnly=false; aAge=23ms; cAge=16860ms",
            nocache: Cookie="nocache=1; Expires=Sun, 30 Jun 2019 11:51:59 GMT; Max-Age=86400; Domain=wellgosh.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; hostOnly=false; aAge=16ms; cAge=16855ms",
            external_no_cache: Cookie="external_no_cache=1; Expires=Sat, 29 Jun 2019 12:51:59 GMT; Max-Age=3600; Domain=wellgosh.com; Path=/; HttpOnly; hostOnly=false; aAge=20ms; cAge=1198ms"
          }
        }
      } }
    }
  }
```

```
function logCookies(cookieJar){
    cookieJar._jar.store.getAllCookies(function(err, cookieArray) {
        if(err) throw new Error("Failed to get cookies");
        let format = (JSON.stringify(cookieArray, null, 4));
        // let format = (cookieArray.map(cookie => cookie.toString()))
        console.log(format)
        pupLaunch(format)
    });

async function pupLaunch(format) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        //args: ['--proxy-server=' + proxy]
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80 Safari/537.36');
    await page.goto(url);
    for(x in cookieArray.length){
    await page.setCookie(JSON.parse(format)[x])
    }

}
```

However, the page loaded without the cookies imported properly.

How can I convert the jar so that it works within puppeteer?

Answer (score 0):

**Use cookies before the navigation**

```
 const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setCookie(...cookies);
    await page.goto(URL);
```